# How to use import headers?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

Trying to run a Suitelet script to call a search and transform into an invoice. But before going into the next step I have encountered the message below:

> Fail to evaluate script: All SuiteScript API Modules are unavailable while executing your define callback.

My script:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */
require(['N/search','N/log'], function (search,log) {
  function onRequest(context) {
    // Search
    // ### ORDERS TO BILL 
var salesorderSearchObj = search.create({
    type: "salesorder",
    filters:
    [
       ["type","anyof","SalesOrd"], 
       "AND", 
       ["status","anyof","SalesOrd:E","SalesOrd:F"], 
       "AND", 
       ["mainline","is","T"]
    ],
    columns:
    [
       search.createColumn({name: "amount", label: "Amount"}),
       search.createColumn({name: "entity", label: "Name"}),
       search.createColumn({name: "account", label: "Account"}),
       search.createColumn({
          name: "datecreated",
          sort: search.Sort.DESC,
          label: "Date Created"
       }),
       search.createColumn({name: "billeddate", label: "Date Billed"}),
       search.createColumn({name: "statusref", label: "Status"})
    ]
 });

 var searchResultCount = salesorderSearchObj.runPaged().count;
 log.debug( {"title":"salesorderSearchObj result count", "details":searchResultCount});
 salesorderSearchObj.run().each(function(result){
    // .run().each has a limit of 4,000 results
    return true;
 });

  }

  return {
    onRequest: onRequest
  };
});
```

It is to map and reduce selected sales orders.

1. Load search.
2. Map by transforming selected orders into one (by customer).
3. Reduce into one invoice/cash sale.

Comment: This looks like you pasted together some random samples. Netsuite help has basic samples of most script types. If you are trying to create a suitelet start with that sample. If you are trying to create a map reduce start there.  Your original script can be run in the console but doesn’t match the signature of any script type.   Also note that your sales order status filter should have the values in an array

Comment: One thing to remember is always use `define` in your scripts instead of `require`. Only use `require` when using the debugging console or browser console.

Answer (score 0):

AS bknights suggested, script samples provided by NetSuite are just part of a script and they are not complete scripts. So before using them, you need to make sure your script is valid and complete.

As for the error message `Fail to evaluate script`, all of your script(which uses NetSuite modules) needs to be in a function inside the callback. i.e Suitelet has one entryPoint `onRequest` so shifting all of your script (in callback) under it should work.

example:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */
define(['N/search'], function (search) {
  function onRequest(context) {
    // Your search and order transform code should be here
    // ### ORDERS TO BILL 

  }

  return {
    onRequest: onRequest
  };
});
```

For further reading check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4387799600.html) out.

Comment: was trying to use the sample on this website, as Netsuite also only showed snippets of things that could be used. https://netsuite-tutorial.blogspot.com/2017/05/suitescript2.html Tried using the example pattern that you've shown which still returned an error. Not sure how to go about this. Thanks.

Comment: was also trying to use the examples on https://4517166-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4345764122.html for paginated search on suitelet, which returned an error as well.

Comment: Above script is working for me, what is the error message now? I mean did it change? and can you post your updated script?

Comment: "SuiteScript 2.0 entry point scripts must implement one script type function." Is the error received.

Comment: You need to use `define` in server-side scripts. I didn't see that, I have updated my answer. Can you try again?

Comment: Thanks it works now ! Except that records exceed 4000, SSS_SEARCH_FOR_EACH_LIMIT_EXCEEDED", will try to do the paginated search